# How to connect two separate ubuntu machines to the same hadoop cluster

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, vmware

I'm using Hadoop to do some data analysis for a university project. My university has kindly given me access to a Machine, the system is running Ubuntu .
Before I put anything on this system I am testing it on my own laptop. I have Virtual Machine VMware and a Ubuntu installation on it.
As my "main work" is being done on my Virtual Machine, thus far I'm using Hadoop on a single cluster (defying the whole point of the "big data analysis" part of my project).
Is there a way for me to connect that machine to my Virtual machine VMware version of Ubuntu to at least demonstrate a cluster of two nodes, or is this impossible as they are not on the same network?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want hadoop multinode installation shell script go bellow link.
https://github.com/tonyreddy/Cloudera-Hadoop-2.0.0-MultiNode-shell-script
download the script and install it will work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the host names in the Host File
2. Perform Passwordless SSH
3. While starting you have to make one of the system as namenode. Either laptop or the System provided.
4. Change the HDFS-Site.xml, as per the namenode of your choice.